# How to validate CAPTCHA correctly in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, validation, captcha, contacts

I'm in the middle of coding CAPTCHA in JavaScript, and I'm trying to get the validation for a contact form to work properly. I'm almost there, the form won't be submitted until the CAPTCHA text-field is entered, but the problem is I'm still getting an error message when I entered the CAPTCHA code correctly.

```
<script>
function ValidateContactForm()
{
var name = document.ContactForm.name;
var phone = document.ContactForm.phone;
var code = document.ContactForm.code;

    if (name.value == "")
{
    window.alert("Please enter your name.");
    name.focus();
    return false;
}

if (phone.value == "")
{
    window.alert("Please enter a valid phone number..");
    phone.focus();
    return false;
}

if (code.value == "")
{
    window.alert("Please enter the code as displayed on screen."); 
    code.focus();
    return false;
    }
    else if (code.value != "") 
{
        window.alert("Your code does not match. Please try again."); 
    code.focus();
    return false;
 }

else {
    return true;
}

return true;
}
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It's really impossible to tell from your code what the problem is. What error message are you getting? From whom? Where?

Comment: I'm creating a contact form, and I'm testing it to see if the CAPTHCA function works. Even though I typed the CAPTCHA code correctly, I still get the error message "Your code does not match..."; so far I've programmed it in a way where the form can't tell if the code has been correctly entered or not and comes with the error message all the time. I think it's the else if (code.value != "") that's causing the problem.

Comment: You're checking the code's value against `""`, if it isn't the empty string, your print that message and return false. I _assume_ that's not intentional?

Comment: IF this helps --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614467/pure-javascript-jquery-html-captcha

Answer (score 0):

Check this lines, the problem is here:

```
if (code.value == "")
{
    window.alert("Please enter the code as displayed on screen."); 
    code.focus();
    return false;
}
else if (code.value != "") 
{
    window.alert("Your code does not match. Please try again."); 
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    code.focus();
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    return false;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 }
else {

    return true;
}
```

This code will return false every time.