# Google reCAPTCHA: show only digits in recaptcha image?

Tags: recaptcha

I am hoping to use Google's free reCAPTCHA service on a web form.

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display

However, I don't want the distorted letters or words to show in recaptcha images. I feel these distorted letters give visitors too much frustration, and I did read negative comments about using distorted words as the challenge. So I hope that only digits show up in recaptcha images.

Is this something developers like us can configure and control? I googled and did not find anything I want.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: reCAPTCHA used to have text from scanned books, and users were helping to digitize them. Lately they've been displaying house numbers from Google Street View. It's hard to say what they'll display next.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no way to configure this. Google will decide how it wants to verify the user. Sometimes, no input is required, the user just checks the box. Other times, digits or letters are required to be typed.

Comment: I am abandoning Google reCapature.

Comment: i think best is to rely on Google what to display as it gives us strong protection against automated scripts or bots attack. Deciding on displaying just digits is like creating option for simulated attacks (bots are becoming smarter). Google is strengthening reCaptcha. One alternate approach is to use mod_security.