# Google nocaptcha post from server to siteverify says details are missing

Tags: node.js, post, recaptcha

```
[ { hostname: 'www.google.com',
    path: '/recaptcha/api/siteverify',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Content-Length': 556 } },
  '{"secret":"XXXUseThisForCommunicationBetweenYourSiteAndGoogleXXX","response":"03AHJ_VuusXdr5IdGpNzQPRjedGs-Le066Fx9r-Lk1gIfLqlzwxapPx70_LukmcOsw3x-m2DSfpvQVylx060H9IjFP82fy7505_t_rjSivauiwBUyQPrBMp5kTRviq_DD1L2mVMTTrBieUMlQM69AIuG3KwmdOQMyMJS2iJdRuRNnvAmDlPSejkASR4X-7c4IIP3NoMb52Qsl9QPeU6kGaPtxqmf1IpNwbSC3bzLXQD-QV1aI4GgaeqSPfOO8EPfISJMQ5kbCd9wqAwHqDAXMtNSvz10Ty30R71HqmsSk7YHddFQhei1L6y9j7nxnY5QtAxHehhpYwJVNjI96hxeIaG58_CQHGbAufy4aPGAlf-zJ6be_Xtdzd4AnHxiX9OuCKQI8eQlh6DZLGaymxXDmPNu4TijGyyu0VeTPTTKf12zVUg86_0ZmszWZDtALjnNnxBH7bZqrgWXhy","remoteip":"00.00.000.000"}' ]
```

If I post that and google returns this:

```
{ success: false, 'error-codes': [ 'missing-input-response', 'missing-input-secret'] }
```

I don't see what is happening wrong

https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin#site/XXXXXX?setup says:

> When your users submit the form where you integrated reCAPTCHA, you'll get as part of the payload a string with the name "g-recaptcha-response". In order to check whether Google has verified that user, send a POST request with these parameters:
>   URL: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify
>   **secret**(required) - XXXXXX, 
>   **response**(required) - The value of 'g-recaptcha-response',
>   **remoteip** - The end user's ip address.

I have clearly sent all these things! What could be happening here? **The error does not say they are wrong, it says they are 'missing'**

And the above Quoted text from google clearly says POST not GET [Google reCAPTCHA: how to get user response and validate in the server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27297067/google-recaptcha-how-to-get-user-response-and-validate-in-the-server-side#answer-27313658)

But if I try a GET request then the response is `[ null, 400, undefined ]`

### UPDATE

As @mscdex pointed out application/x-www-form-urlencoded is required but the responce still said that it was missing the secret so I url encoded this instead as I figured something bad may be happening to the item at the start of the object.

```
{'_':'_','secret':'XXXXXX','response':'whateverXXYsgTSG','remoteip':'00.00.000.000'}
```

And finally it worked:

```
[ { hostname: 'www.google.com',
    path: '/recaptcha/api/siteverify?',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: 
     { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
       'Content-Length': 548 } },
  '"_=_&secret=XXXXXX&response=03AHJ_VuurQFgsftybLlvrdGOwXfNneWp4v7FPJJbOD9CGpiHAkFBaiNy7YWXcHrAkU6SPU5UZpgKCptU3gRX5OPqXEh2qqP3nXJpiBWoxFW_Iv05P2UA23rzzZk0ecScmMSL1PP1uyBCdJ08HpAWEuz2PzL6m6u71k09xQbVbPZ5KT6qnb-mdPNyEkdBxtc9a5oYpnOoHg7ax6q4Ms4Lis4qrNBLCavKmYZ6vAmYitSEI0a0GERnlI3wLSvayhc-Yygv1koKIjg2q8GHXV1UhKLzBa8t8x2ibRBNwXUMBFs3Qj_lfwgiTNtIaU3kEAFPULJulZDOsAcovKpjk5xkyMM2C5YDGYMioeyOMl9ZmyyvkwfrrRe8e9o_tD6SaTTSAcrcxsfYGm-w0_CDbsa2IWSkjiMN-2B9SClOZJGXXVXVIuIYClIK3XuUvTsObCzxJAq2IKwwMTtYX&remoteip=00.00.000.000"' ]
[ { success: true }, 200, undefined ]
```

**But I would like to do this properly not hacky** So if anyone can answer how to do it properly that would be swell!

```
var JSON={
        https:require('https')
    ,   toquery:require('../node_modules/querystring').stringify
    ,   stringify:require('../node_modules/json-stringify-safe')
    ,   parse:require('../node_modules/try-json-parse')
    ,   get:function(url,callback){process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED="0";var req=JSON.https.request(url,function(res){var buffer='';res.setEncoding('utf8');res.on('data',function(chunk){buffer+=chunk;});res.on('end',function(){try{var data=JSON.parse(buffer);callback(data,res.statusCode);}catch(e){console.log(e);}});});req.end();}
    ,   post:function(url,path,data,type,callback){if(!callback){callback=type;type=undefined;}data=JSON.stringify(data);var options={hostname:url,path:path,method:'POST',headers:{'Content-Type':type||'application/json','Content-Length':data.length}};console.dir([options,data]);var req=JSON.https.request(options,function(res){var buffer='';res.setEncoding('utf8');res.on('data',function(chunk){buffer+=chunk;});res.on('end',function(){try{var data=JSON.parse(buffer);callback(data,res.statusCode);}catch(e){console.log(e);}});});req.write(data);req.end();}
        };

JSON.post(
        'www.google.com'
    ,   '/recaptcha/api/siteverify?'
    ,   JSON.toquery({'_':'_','secret':'XXXX','response':response,'remoteip':remoteip})
    ,   'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    ,   function(data,result,statusCode){
            console.dir([data,result,statusCode]);
            if(result.success){}
            else{}
            });
```

Comment: Are you sure the API allows an `application/json` POST submission? Perhaps it's expecting an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` POST instead?

Comment: Updated my question based on this

Comment: Ok, so show how are you making the request.

Comment: Updated to show the code

Comment: That looks alright to me and you said it works. Why do you call it "hacky?"

Comment: because I have appended `_:_` to the front of the query (its a variable that google does not expect to be there). I would say at this point that they have a bug. Because I am posing correctly without appending a foo variable to the start. But they seam to eat the first variable every time. so it would seem that the only way to get a proper response from them is to hack and add an extra variable of no meaning whatsoever to the front of the payload.

Comment: Thank you for your help @mscdex I am going to keep this question open for anyone to answer (I will be looking to accept). I will in the mean time use this code but, proceed with caution as; I feel sending an unexpected result to a third party is bad practice and could at any time stop working.

Comment: every other API in the world expects/allows application/json and then there's Google who don't allow it, give no error and don't even mention how you're supposed to send those

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I do it in one of my project using [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent). This is my recaptcha-helper.js

```
var request = require("superagent");

var config = {
  recaptcha: {
    secret: "XXXXX",
    url: "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify",
  },
};

var ERROR_CODES = {
  "missing-input-secret": "Unexpected Server Error (1)",
  "invalid-input-secret": "Unexpected Server Error (2)",
  "missing-input-response": "Missing reCAPTCHA value",
  "invalid-input-response": "Invalid reCATPCHA value",
};

exports.getErrorCode = function (errorCode) {
  if (Array.isArray(errorCode)) {
    var errors = errorCode.map(function (code) {
      return exports.getErrorCode(code);
    });
    return errors.join("\n");
  }
  return ERROR_CODES[errorCode] ||
    (errorCode ? ("Unexpected reCAPTCHA error: " + errorCode) : "Unexpected reCAPTCHA error");
};

exports.parseResponse = function (err, res) {
  if (err) {
    return { success: false, error: err };
  } else if (!res.body.success) {
    var error = new Error(exports.getErrorCode(res.body["error-codes"]));
    return { success: false, error: error };
  } else {
    return { success: true };
  }
};

exports.verify = function (response, ip) {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "test") {
    return response ? Promise.resolve() :
      Promise.reject(new Error("Test reCAPTCHA Error"));
  }

  return new Promise (function (resolve, reject) {
    request.post(config.recaptcha.url)
    .type("form")
    .accept("json")
    .send({
      secret: config.recaptcha.secret,
      response: response,
      remoteip: ip,
    })
    .end(function (err, res) {
      var parsedRes = exports.parseResponse(err, res);
      return parsedRes.success ? resolve() : reject(parsedRes.error);
    });
  });
};
```

And you can use it doing

```
var captchaHelper = require('./recaptcha-helper');

captchaHelper.verify(req.body.captcha, req.ip)
  .then(function () {
    // on success
  }).catch(function (err {
   // on error
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by passing **secret** and **response** as a query parameter:

Example :

```
axios.post("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret="
+ 'XXXXXX' + "&response=" + response + "&remoteip=" + req.connection.remoteAddress);
```