# Is there a way to request the "response" parameter of Google reCaptcha having the site secret key?

Tags: javascript, php, recaptcha

I want to use a QR code to submit a form (through GET), but this form is also validated by Google reCaptcha, i wonder if is there a way to pass the **response** parameter used to validate the reCaptcha in the url presented by the QR code.

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27297067/google-recaptcha-how-to-get-user-response-and-validate-in-the-server-side) SO question?

Comment: Well... recaptcha is precisely made to prevent "robots" so i guess this is not possible, or there is a big leak in recaptcha ;)